# never saw/have seen

Tags: past-vs-present-perfect

I have recently read:

> I never saw this movie (instead of "I have never seen this movie")

I believe that the Present Perfect is usually used with the adverb "**never**" because the event can still happen in the present. Example: I have never talked to my biological father (**exception**: I never talked to my biological father and I found out today that he is dead). Is that correct?

In which context the sentence in question could be correct with the Simple Past?

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to find a context for that sentence. The idea is that verbs in *Present* Perfect tell us something about the *present*, and verbs in *Past* Simple tell us something about the *past*.

'Never' doesn't necessarily trigger the use of Present Perfect, because it can refer to the past and future, too, like in "I will never marry you!"

As for the 'never' in a past tense, just imagine that someone tells you about things that are gone, that are not connected with the present. For example, Jack tells about his childhood:

> As a child, **I never saw this movie**, although it was quite famous then. Only last year I saw it for the first time.

Comment: Could it be  As a child I had never seen this movie although it was quite famous...because this statement had been true until last year when he saw it

Comment: @user5577 - I don't think so. With Past Perfect there has got to be a **moment** in the past _before_ which the statement was true, like in "I had never seen that film before my dad bought a VHS cassette with it." In my example, "as a child" is no way a moment. The next sentence is about a quite different time plane, which is not connected with Jack's childhood. Both sentences use Past Simple as it is a usual way when enumerating things that happened one after another, or when telling a story, like in "I woke up, got up, had breakfast, and went to the office."

Comment: "to be connected with the present" seems vague and subjective to me. For instance, I could say: As a child, I never saw/have seen this movie, and I still feel sad for that. Have you meant specifically that the event could still *happen* in the explicit/implicit time period of the sentence ?

Comment: Before last  year, I had not seen that movie in my childhood.  Past last year past of the past before last yearb

Comment: @AlanEvangelista - If you say "As a child, I never have seen this movie", it will mean you are still a child. If your childhood is in the past, you cannot use a present tense to speak about it, you'll need a past tense. And yes, subjective, because we say what _we_ want, not what the language "demands" (as we imagine it), it is we that use the language, not the language that uses us.

Comment: @YellowSky we can say what we want, regardless if a rule is objective or subjective. I don't see how that answers my question. What I meant is that in certain contexts, an event may be interpreted to be connected with the present or not, as the example of a fact of my childhood.

Comment: @YellowSky English uses Present Perfect to speak about past events all the time (eg I have graduated before I started to work). Why not the same for my childhood, as long as it is connected to the present somehow?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista - Present Perfect is a _present_ tense, what's not clear? If you know it all so well, why asking the question? Here a teacher (me) is explaining you things as they are, but you have your own point of view, right? The English grammar should work the way _you_ think it should, not the way it really works?